# How to load a csv file to hbase from local directory?

Tags: import, load, hbase, local

I tried to load a csv from my local directory to hbase using similar command we have for hdfs but it failed.
I dont want to put my file into hdfs and load to hbase. Is there a way to load the data into hbase from local.
The below did not help

```
     hbase(main):010:0> hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator="," \
-Dimporttsv.columns="HBASE_ROW_KEY,events:driverId,events:driverName,events:eventTime,events:eventType,events:latitudeColumn,events:longitudeColumn,events:routeId,events:routeName,events:truckId" \
irfan_ns:driver_dangerous_event \
file:///home/aziz/driver
```

**Error**

> SyntaxError: (hbase):10: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER

Comment: is there any reason you don't want to put file in hdfs ?

Comment: We dont want to install hdfs. That is why. Anyways i found the answer from another post. The above command is not a hbase command. The above command runs fine from shell prompt.